# Why doesn't SimpleAuthorityMapper's mapAuthorities method doesn't work in Spring Securit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
```

I have

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
```

and if I use this line

```
grantedAuthorityMapper.setDefaultAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
```

then I can access my API endpoints. However if I use these two lines:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
grantedAuthorityMapper.mapAuthorities(grantedAuthorityList);
```

then I cannot access my API endpoints.

I think `mapAuthorities` method doesn't work or I'm missing something or I'm doing something wrong.

These are the final two lines:

```
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

Comment: without providing proper debug logs, more context, And/Or a small reproducible example this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
grantedAuthorityMapper.setDefaultAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
```

actually set `ROLE_ADMIN` as a default authority that will always be added to the list of the mapped authorities when `keycloakAuthenticationProvider` will map the authorities of the authenticated user.

The authentication provider will actually call `mapAuthorities` for that.

The ollowing 2 lines are having no effect because the mapped authorities returned by `mapAuthorities` are not reused:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER");
grantedAuthorityMapper.mapAuthorities(grantedAuthorityList);
```

You should not use `grantedAuthorityMapper` directly, it should be used by the identity and authentication provider to map the authorities of the user.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be, that you need to add:

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"})
```

to your (controller)classes?